# Usar v-for en Sub Object Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Como se podría mostrar un elemento de este array de objetos

```
export default {
name: 'app',
data () {
    return {
        items: [
            {
                message: 'Foo',
                submenus: [
                    {
                        item_submenu: '01',
                        item_submenu: '02'
                    }
                ]
            },
            { 
                message: 'Bar' 
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Lo intenté mostrar así y no aparecen los item_submenu

```
#app
    nav
        ul
            li(v-for="item in items") {{ item.message }} - {{ item.submenus }}
        ul
            li(v-for="submenu in items.submenus") {{ submenu.item_submenu }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error de indentanción. Pug interpreta los espacios/tabs como Python; si un elemento está dentro (identado) de otro, significa que es su hijo. En tu caso, tienes las dos etiquetas `ul` **al mismo nivel**, causando que `submenu` **no esté disponible** en la segunda lista.

```
#app
  ul
    li(v-for="item in items")
      |{{ item.message }}
      ul
        li(v-for="submenu in item.submenus")
          |{{ submenu.item_submenu }}
```

Comment: Asi solo me muestra lo siguiente
-Foo
--02
-Bar
es decir no se ejecuta el segundo for

Comment: ¿Cómo que no? `02` está **dentro del array anidado**. Se está iterando ambos for correctamente.

Comment: Solo me muestra el ultimo en el segundo for , agree otro item_submenu: '03', y solo me muestra ese, estoy usando single file components

Comment: Porque el array anidado **tiene solo un objeto** y además **sobreescribes** `item_submenu` haciendo que el primero desaparezca.

Comment: Listo gracias c:

Comment: Si te servió mi respuesta, considera marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione el array estaba mal y también la identacion

```
    export default {
    name: 'app',
    data () {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    message: 'Foo',
                    submenus: [
                        {
                            item_submenu: '01',
                        },
                        { 
                            item_submenu: '02' 
                        }
                    ]
                },
                { 
                    message: 'Bar' 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Y en el template

```
#app
    ul
        li(v-for="item in items")
            |{{ item.message }}
            ul
                li(v-for="submenu in item.submenus")
                    |{{ submenu.item_submenu }}
```